# find same value/name from array and merge them into one

Tags: javascript

I want to change an array of objects into a new array, but objects with the same `name` should be merged into one object that has all the `id`s included and all the `count`s summed.

For example:

```
var originalArray = [
  { id: 2, name: "Test", Count: 2 },
  { id: 3, name: "NotTest", Count: 1 },
  { id: 4, name: "someOtherName", Count: 1 },
  { id: 5, name: "Test", Count: 1 },
  { id: 6, name: "Test", Count: 1 }
];
```

would become:

```
var newArray = [
  { id: 3, name: "NotTest", Count: 1 },
  { id: 4, name: "someOtherName", Count: 1 },
  { id: [2,5,6], name: "Test", Count: 4 }
];
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Could you clear that it will be a single array or array of array ?

Comment: it will be single array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does almost exactly what you want. The [reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) starts with an empty `acc` array and, for each item in the orginal array, updates the matching item in the `acc` array if any, or else adds a new item.

Note that:

1. The value of the `id` property is always an array of IDs, even if the count for that name is equal to 1. (You can change this by doing something like:

   `if(item.id.length == 1){item.id = item.id[0];}` .)
2. The order of the original array is not necessarily preserved. (If this matters, you can add a sort function to move the unmatched items to the top.)

```js
const currentArray = getData(); // Binds original array to `currentArray`

const newArray = currentArray.reduce( (acc, curr) => {
  // Checks whether the current name already exists in the `acc` array 
  const match = acc.find(item => item.name == curr.name);
  if(match){
    // Changes the matching item's `id` and `count` properties
    match.id.push(curr.id);
    match.count += curr.count;
  }
  else{
    // Copies current item, giving the copy an array as the `id` value
    const newItem = Object.assign({}, curr, {id: [curr.id]});
    acc.push(newItem); // Adds the copy to the new new array
  }
  // Gets ready for next item (or returns result if no items left)
  return acc; 
}, []); // Sets `acc` to start as an empty array

console.log(newArray);

function getData(){
  return [
    {id: 2, name: "Test", count: 1},
    {id: 3, name: "NotTest", count: 1},
    {id: 4, name: "someOtherName", count: 1},
    {id: 5, name: "Test", count: 1},
    {id: 6, name: "Test", count: 2}
  ];
}
```